# Is a compact set on a Polish space closed?

Tags: real-analysis, stochastic-analysis

**Proposition**: If an exponentially tight familiy $P_\epsilon$ satisfies the LDP (large deviation principle) lower bound for open sets for a rate function I, then I is a good rate function.

The proof now starts with: Let $a>0$ be given and $K_a$ be the corresponding (compact) set from exponential tightness. Note that $K_a^c$ is open,...

My problem is, that I don't see, why we know that $K_a^c$ is open. We are working on a Polish space, and as far as I know, compact doesn't implie closed here, does it?

P.S. LDP lower bound for open sets: For all $G \in X$ open, we have $\liminf_{\epsilon \to 0} \epsilon \ln  \mathbb{P}_\epsilon [G] \geq -\inf_{x \in G} I(x)$  where $I(x)$ is a lower semicontinuous function.

exponential tightness: For all $a>0$ there exists a compact set $K_a$ such that $\limsup_{\epsilon \to 0} \epsilon  \ln \mathbb{P}_\epsilon [K_a^c]<-a$

Comment: Compact sets are closed in any Hausdorff space, and Polish spaces are Hausdorff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A polish space is metrizable; that is, it is homeomorphic to a metric space. In a metric space the general Heine-Borel Theorem holds, so that a compact set is complete and therefore necessarily closed. Homeomorphisms preserve the properties of compactness and being closed, so the set must also be closed in the original space.